# eb init ERROR while trying to deploy app on aws beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I get the following error when I use command  "`eb init`" in a newly made project parent folder.

> ERROR: TypeError :: string indices must be integers

my project folder contain one `index.html` file from which directory I am running this command.

[image: error image]

after running command "eb init --debug", output was->

[debug image part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbzSy.png)

[debug image part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw3Mt.png)

Comment: What version of the EB CLI are you running? You can find out by running `eb --version`. If you are not on the latest try updating the CLI. If the error still occurs run it with the `--debug` command to get more verbose results.

Comment: @nbalas EB CLI 3.10.1 (Python 2.7.1) is my eb cli version

Comment: I would run the same command again like this: `eb init --debug` and add that to your question to provide additional information.

Comment: @nbalas please check my debug image uploaded.